# sum of duplicates data list on java

Tags: java

I have this code

```
    ... some code here

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Document next = iterator.next();

      projectNumber = new NpoProjectNumberVM();
      localDate = new java.sql.Date(((Date) next.get("_id")).getTime()).toLocalDate();
      projectNumber.setDay(localDate);
      projectNumber.setNumber(((Long) next.get("number")).intValue());
      projectNumberList.add(projectNumber);
    }

    return projectNumberList;
```

which displays this result

```
 "projectNumber": [
        {
            "day": "2022-02-07",
            "number": 2
        },
        {
            "day": "2022-02-07",
            "number": 1
        },
        {
            "day": "2022-02-07",
            "number": 4
        },
    ]
```

My request is: I want to have the sum of the numbers for the same date like this

```
 "projectNumber": [
        {
            "day": "2022-02-07",
            "number": 7
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `Map` where the key is the date, so you can verify if it exists or not then do the good logic

```
static List<Document> method() {
    Map<LocalDate, Document> projects = new HashMap<>();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Document next = iterator.next();

        localDate = new java.sql.Date(((Date) next.get("_id")).getTime()).toLocalDate();
        int nb = ((Long) next.get("number")).intValue();

        if (projects.containsKey(localDate)) {
            projects.get(projectNumber).setNumber(nb + projects.get(projectNumber).getNumber());
        } else {
            projectNumber = new NpoProjectNumberVM();
            projectNumber.setDay(localDate);
            projectNumber.setNumber();
            projects.put(localDate, projectNumber);
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(projects.values());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Java 8 streams: GroupingBy

Use Java 8 streaming with some of the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) like [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) for the *key* and [`summingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-) for the *aggregate*-function to return a `Map<?, Long>` (where ? stands for the key, here `LocalDate`):

```java
Map<LocalDate, Long> sumByDay = projectNumberList.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(
        ProjectNumber::getDay,
        summingLong(ProjectNumber::getNumber)
    )
);
```

See also:

- Baeldung: [Guide to Java 8 groupingBy Collector, 2.7. Getting the Sum from Grouped Results](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector#7-getting-the-sum-from-grouped-results)

#### JSON output

To produce some JSON output like

```json
"projectNumber": [
        {
            "day": "2022-02-07",
            "number": 7
        },
        {
            "day": "2022-02-01",
            "number": 1
        }
]
```

you could use *Jackson* with a custom Map-serializer.